# nginx webdav server with auth request

Tags: authentication, nginx, webdav

My nginx.conf:

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
  alias /home/username/apidav/$remote_user/$1;

  client_body_temp_path       /var/www/path/;
  client_max_body_size        50m;
  dav_methods                 PUT DELETE MKCOL;# COPY MOVE;
  create_full_put_path        on;
  dav_access                  user:rw  group:rw  all:r;
  dav_ext_methods             PROPFIND OPTIONS;
  auth_request /api_auth;
}

location /api_auth {
  internal;
  proxy_pass http://www.domain.ru/accounts/api_auth/;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

curl -T test.txt 'http://gert:passwd@www.domain.ru/api/' curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer?

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: https://serverfault.com/questions/449195/nginx-webdav-server-with-auth-request.
Thanks to [Maxim Dounin](https://serverfault.com/users/132187/maxim-dounin).